# Half of speed for 1Gbit/1Gibt network on RotuerOS mikrotik

Tags: router, nat, mikrotik-routeros

I have Mikrotik router which is configured with basic guides. I reset router when I got it from a friend and configured from scratch. Problem is speed is maximum 500Mbit/500Mbit instead of 1Gbit/1Gbit.

I did some tests. Here are results with following configurations:

`ISP <-> ISP Router (bridge port) <-> Laptop` 850/900Mbit
`ISP <-> ISP Router (bridge port) <-> Mikrotik <-> Laptop` Around 500/500Mbit
`ISP <-> ISP Router (bridge port) <-> Mikrotik <-> switch <-> Laptop` Around 500/500Mbit

I also tried downloading From 2 computers at same time. Max WAN transfer is around 500/500Mbit

My router model is RB750Gr3 with RouterOS v6.43.7

When testing speed between 2 computers connected to same group of bridged interfaces speeds are close to 900/900Mbit between two computers. So basically bottleneck is between Mikrotik WAN port.

While testing speedtest there is around 30% CPU usage.

My main goal is to know what is a bottleneck of this router.

Accordnig to charts it should be capable of 1Gbit+ speeds with 1500 MTU
https://mikrotik.com/product/RB750Gr3#fndtn-testresults

My NAT table is as follows:

```
0    chain=srcnat action=masquerade out-interface=internet1 out-interface-list=WAN log=no log-prefix="" 
1    chain=dstnat action=dst-nat to-addresses=192.168.5.5 protocol=tcp dst-address=111.111.111.111 in-interface=internet1 dst-port=80 log=no log-prefix="" 
2    chain=dstnat action=dst-nat to-addresses=192.168.5.5 protocol=tcp dst-address=111.111.111.111 dst-port=443 
3    chain=dstnat action=dst-nat to-addresses=192.168.5.5 protocol=tcp dst-address=111.111.111.111 dst-port=8000-8999 
4    chain=dstnat action=dst-nat to-addresses=192.168.5.5 protocol=tcp dst-address=111.111.111.111 dst-port=32400 log=yes log-prefix="" 
5    chain=dstnat action=dst-nat to-addresses=192.168.5.5 protocol=udp dst-address=111.111.111.111 dst-port=32400 log=no log-prefix=""
```

Comment: @EchoMike444 Partially. with 500Mbps speed I have 33% CPU usage. I want to know why it does not allow higher rates despite lots of resources still free (RAM is at 8%). 
Theoretically it should be able to get 1.8GBPS with ~1500 frame size.

Answer (score 0):

From:  https://www.vanilla.co.za/hardware/mikrotik-RB750.php

> It's a small five port gigabit ethernet router with more functionality
>   than we think it should have, and will work for speeds up to 350 Mbps.

Looking down the table, you are getting about the maximum throughput for this router that you can get.

You would need a faster router to get better speed.

Comment: Theoretical 350Mbps and my 450-550Mbps (up and down) does not match. Also table says *Observed max speed: 500 - 900 Mbps*
Also, would be really interested what's a bottleneck here (It's not RAM nor CPU).
I got it from friend, wanted to buy *RB4011IGS+RM* and not sure to do so. What if it also will be bottlenecked because of something?

Comment: I always need a router here with more throughput than the speed my ISP supplies. I think for my routers that the highest theoretical speed is just the highest possible speed in perfect conditions and I do not get perfect conditions.